# Android Studio Emulator device screen capture screen not available

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, screen-capture

Using Android Studio in Windows. Trying to get the screenshot.

1. Run my App in Debug Mode.
2. Open the Android DDMS tool window.
3. Click Screen Capture on the left side of the Android DDMS tool window.

When the Device Screen Capture window appears, "save" button is disabled and shows Screen not available.

Comment: You can try `Snipping Tool` on Windows. Press the start button and type `Snipping Tool`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Android Virtual Device Manager (AVD) try unchecking the virtual devices Emulated Performance settings: use host GPU.

Answer (score 2):

Using @NataliaMaciejowska answer, I also changed emulator settings:

[image]

But it didn't help. I reinstalled video player drivers, started other emulators with lower API level. Strange, but I also didn't receive a screenshot or video, while devices showed them. Sometimes later emulators started to show screenshots. Don't know, what happened. Also don't forget to switch between emulators here:

[image]

You can try to take a screenshot with emulator's button:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use adb screenrecord

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/shell.html#screenrecord

```
$ adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/demo.mp4
(press Ctrl-C to stop)
$ adb pull /sdcard/demo.mp4
$ adb shell rm /sdcard/demo.mp4
```